# stochastic optimal control/FOC/Reis(2021)

Tags: mathematical-economics, fiscal-policy, optimal-control

> Reis (2021) `The constraint on public debt when $r < g$ but $g < m$' :
> HJB:
> $$\rho V(a, q) = \max_{c/a, k/a} [\log c + V'(a,q)[r + (mq-r)\frac{k}{a} - \frac{c}{a}] a + \frac{V''(a,q)}{2} (k/a)^2 \delta^2 a^2 + v \int ((V(a,q') - V(a,q)) dQ(q'|q)]$$
> where $V'(.) = \partial V(.)/\partial a$. It is standard to derive that at an optimum:
> $$c = \rho a$$
> $$\frac{k}{a} = \frac{mq-r}{\delta(q)^2}$$
> $$V'(.) = \frac1{\rho a}$$
> $$ \lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-\rho t} V'(.) a_t = 0$$

The author says `standard', but I am having difficulty in deriving these FOC. Using $\log c/a + \log a$, I can get $c/a = 1/aV'$. Also, it is easy to get $k/a = -(mq-r)V'/V'' \delta^2 a$. I guess the next step is to differentiate HJB w.r.t. $a$ (the envelope condition). This gives me
$$\rho V' = \frac1a + V'' \mu_a a + V'\mu_a + \frac{V'''}{2} \sigma_a^2 + V'' (k/a)^2 \delta^2 a + v \int (V'(a, q') - V'(a, q) dQ(q'|q)$$
where $\mu_a$ is the drift of $da$ and $\sigma_a$ is the volatility of $da$. For the third FOC in the paper to hold, the terms in right hand side should be cancelled out except $1/a$. But, why is that true? Can you give some help?

You can find the [paper](https://personal.lse.ac.uk/reisr/papers/99-mpkrg.pdf). It is on p.37 (Appendix A).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the "standard" approach in solving HJB equations like this is to guess a form for $V$ and then verify. Your first order conditions for $c/a$ and $k/a$ are right.

Now, guess that $V(a, q) = K\log(a)$. With this you get

\begin{align}
c &= \frac{a}{K},\\
\frac{k}{a} &= \frac{mq - r}{\delta(q)^2},\\
V'(.) &= \frac{K}{a}.
\end{align}

The verification step goes as follows. For notational simplicity, define $\xi \equiv \frac{mq - r}{\delta(q)}$ as the market price of risk (the Sharpe ratio). Plug in your guess of $V$ into the HJB and rearrange to get

$$
\underbrace{\rho K\log(a)}_{\text{LHS of HJB}} = \underbrace{\log(a) - \log K + Kr - 1 + \frac{1}{2}K\xi^2}_{\text{RHS of HJB}}.
$$
Comparing the terms involving $a$ on the LHS and RHS, we must have $\rho K = 1$, which when plugged into the FOC's above gives you the FOC's in the text.